# MySQL subquery very slow in huge table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT o_id, someColumn... FROM link_table WHERE s_id = 1 and o_id IN
(SELECT s_id FROM link_table WHERE o_id=2)
```

This sql query is to find out intermediate_id connected between specific s_id and o_id, but seems extremely slow. Take about 10s.

link_table is huge (with 40M rows)

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :** As per my experience **EXISTS** gives better performance over **IN** Cluase

```
SELECT o_id, someColumn... 
FROM link_table t1 
WHERE s_id = 1 and EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                           FROM link_table t2 
                           WHERE t2.s_id=t1.o_id AND t2.o_id=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using self join:::

```
SELECT o_id, someColumn... FROM 
link_table A, link_table b
WHERE a.s_id = 1 AND
a.o_id=b.s_id AND
b.o_id=2
```